# Generate Wi-Fi QRCode with qr-image

Tags: node.js, npm, qr-code

The [npm module qr-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-image) allows generation of QRCodes with NodeJS, like the following:

```js
import qr from 'qr-image';
import fs from 'fs';

qr.image('https://google.com/search?q=hello%20world!', {type:'png'}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myqrcode.png'));
// the qrcode is saved to myqrcode.png
```

Android supports a feature called **Wi-Fi QRCode Generation**, which *creates a QRCode that when scanned on a different device, connects to the Wi-Fi without the need to enter the password*. Is there a way to implement this with the **qr-image** package mentioned above?

I've searched Google and did not find any information useful, and tried using protocols such as `wifi://`, but none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [zxing wiki](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wi-fi-network-config-android-ios-11). In short, the format is `WIFI:S:<SSID>;T:<WPA|WEP|>;P:<password>;;`

For example, the code may be:

```js
import qr from 'qr-image';
import fs from 'fs';

qr.image('WIFI:S:MYSSID;T:WPA;P:"password";;', {type:'png'}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myqrcode.png'));
```

Also, check [wifi-qr-code-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wifi-qr-code-generator). It gives you high level API for your task.

Comment: Confirmed this worked on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Use this tool https://github.com/Intosoft/custoqr

```js
import { generateSVGString, generateContentString } from '@intosoft/custoqr';

const value = generateContentString("wifi",{
    ssid: "",
    password:"",
    encryption:"", // "WEP", "WPA", "nopass"
});

const config = {}; //generate config from https://custoqr.com

const svgString =  generateSVGString({
    ...config,
    value
})
```

**This tool provides fully customizable options for shape, color, logo.**

Comment: Looks nice, I'll give it a try.